# A small number is rounded to zero

Tags: c++, casting, double

I have the following values:

`i->fitness = 160`

`sum_fitness = 826135`

I do the operation:

`i->roulette = (int)(((i->fitness / sum_fitness)*100000) + 0.5);`

But i keep getting `0` in `i->roulette`.

I also tried to save `i->fitness / sum_fitness` in a `double` variable and only then applying the other operations, but also this gets a `0`.

I'm thinking that's because `160/826135` is such a small number, then it rounds it down to `0`.

How can i overcome this?

Thank you

**edit:**

Thanks everyone, i eventually did this:

```
double temp = (double)(i->fitness);
i->roulette = (int)(((temp / sum_fitness)*100000) + 0.5);
```

And it worked.

All the answers are similar so it's hard to choose one.

Comment: using double it gives `19` for me (`int` truncated from `19.8673`)

Comment: What if you write `((double)(I->fitness)) / ((double)sum_fitness))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You line

```
i->roulette = (int)(((i->fitness / sum_fitness)*100000) + 0.5);
```

is casting the value to int which is why any float operation is truncated
try

```
i->roulette = (((i->fitness / sum_fitness)*100000) + 0.5);
```

and make sure that either 'sum_fitness' or 'i->fitness' is of of a float or double type to make the division a floating point division -- if they are not you will need to cast one of them before dividing, like this

```
i->roulette = (((i->fitness / (double)sum_fitness)*100000) + 0.5);
```

If you want to make this as a integer calculation you could also try to change the order of the division and multiplication, like

```
i->roulette = ( i->fitness *100000) / sum_fitness;
```

which would work as long as you don't get any integer overflow, which in your case would occur only if fitness risk to be above 2000000.

Comment: but i'm casting it to `int` only after i multiply it. `160/826135 * 100000 + 0.5 = 19.867`

Comment: Your fitness and sum_fitness also need to be of a float type to make a floating point division, otherwise it is a int division where 3/4 makes 0, and (3/4)*100 also makes 0 because the 3/4 is calculated first due to the () and the ordering of the multiplication.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm thinking that's because `160/826135` is such a small number, then it rounds it down to `0`.

It is *integer division*, and it is *truncated* to the integral part. So yes, it is `0`, but there is no rounding. `99/100` would also be `0`.

You could fix it like by casting the numerator or the denominator to `double`:

```
i->roulette = ((i->fitness / static_cast<double>(sum_fitness))*100000) + 0.5;
```

Comment: So you're saying i should cast them first to `double` and only then do the division? I thought because it's in the right side of the assignment, then it calculates it first, and only then does the cast.

Comment: @AlaaM. If either the numerator or the denominator are `double`, then the result will be double. So casting either before the division would fix that part of the problem. But if you then cast the fraction to `int`, you get truncation again.

Comment: Yes eventually i do want it to be an `integer`, but only after the multiplication.

Comment: @AlaaM. I added a version that should work. If `i->roulette` is an `int`, you don't have to cast the RHS.